# How to get the Enter (Return) key in Messaging (MMS) app - Jelly Bean

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, mms

I have JellyBean 4.2 and my friend also has the same.

I have been fond of using the "Enter" or "return" key while typing messages. I like paragraphs in messages. But I have a "**Smiley**" Button.

My friend however has the enter key. See the Screen shot:

[image: Screen Shot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

How to get the Enter button like in the screen shot?

Comment: I'd start with examining the settings of the Messaging app to see if anything looks relevant.

Comment: I have drilled down my phone for all possible settings. Let alone be that of Messaging App :)

Comment: Fair enough. :-) Which phones have you and your friend got? And are you both using the stock keyboard?

Comment: I am using stock kb of Jelly Bean. I don't know about my friend. Both have a Galaxy S. Both have custom ROMs as well, hence the jelly bean

Comment: If you are using CyanogenMod (or a derivative of it), you can enable the enter key under Messaging -> Menu -> Settings -> Soft Keyboard Type -> Show the Enter Key

Comment: Sadly, the Soft Keyboard Type option is missing from recent CyanogenMod builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my ROM to a CM variant (SlimBean to be specific) and found this in the settings

[image: Messaging App settings]

This worked for me. Thanks to [bassmadrigal's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44443/how-to-get-the-enter-return-key-in-messaging-mms-app-jelly-bean#comment60119_44443).

Comment: Sadly, this option is missing from recent cyanogenmod builds.

Answer (score 19):

press the shift key and see the change in the icon for the smiley. It changes to the enter key.

Comment: This works on Google Keyboard in KitKat 4.4.4.

Comment: this works. if you cannot see it at first you must switch to English lang first and then try pressing shift above number switch key.

Comment: This should really be the recognized answer. Conformed with Google Keyboard and Messenger on Cyanogen OS 12.1

Comment: Doesn't work on Jellybean. I seriously hope whatever marketing dipshit thought this up has lost their job by now.

Answer (score 1):

Messaging -> Menu -> Settings -> Soft Keyboard Type -> Show the Enter Key

Answer (score 1):

You can use newline in Android Jelly Bean while texting too.
While typing hold shift key the smiley icon will change to newline icon then move your finger to that newline button, it gives me newline in my text message.

Just make sure that holding shift and moving finger to that newline button will be done very fast and quick otherwise the button will do some other operation like going to execute "previous" action.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, replace the stock text/messaging app with something like "Textra" from the play store. This will bring back the return key as standard.

Answer (score 0):

Go to GO Keyboard Settings - under 'Input' select 'More..' - select 'Smiley Key Setting' - select 'Off'.  Done!

Comment: This needs a preamble: "*If you're using GO Keyboard, ...*"